# What's a more secure alternative for eval() when I just want to call a function?

Tags: javascript, eval

I know PHP has `call_user_func`, I was just wondering if JavaScript had something similar, where the method I want to call is, for example: `object.set$fieldID($fieldValue)`

I would rather not go through if/else/switch blocks just to execute one line of code properly.

If it helps, I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
object["set" + $fieldID]($fieldValue);
```

Some reading material for the above: [Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) on [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En).

Some advanced methods include [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). The first is *somehow* equivalent to PHP's `call_user_func()` while the latter is *somehow* equivalent to PHP's `call_user_func_array()`.

The difference between PHP's functions and JavaScript's is that JavaScript allows you to call methods of some object in the context of another object. This is done through the use of the first argument of `call()` and `apply()`.

An equivalent for the above example, but using `call()` and `apply()` looks like this:

```
object["set" + $fieldID].call(object, $fieldValue);
object["set" + $fieldID].apply(object, [$fieldValue]);
```

The first argument must be `object` otherwise the method will be executed with the `this` pointer bound to the global object, `window` in the case of browsers.

Comment: You sir, are a diamond geezer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

@lonut is correct.  More generally though, if you want to call functions that aren't a part of an explicit object (e.g.: global), you can call them on the `window` object:

```
var foo = function() { alert(1); };
window['foo']();
```

since all objects are contained in `window`.

Another example:

```
var object = function() { this.method = function() { alert(2); }; }
var instance = new object();
window['instance']['method']();
```

Comment: Yes, calling global functions using `window` or something like `this['foo']();` (when the global object isn't named `window`) is useful. +1