# javascript: call a function in a closure scope

Tags: javascript

Is there any way I can override a closure so it does part of what the original closure does? I know there's no straightforward way, but is there some hack? I'm willing to be messy...

```
<html>
    <head>

        // I DON'T CONTROL THIS CODE!!!
        <script>
        ;(function() {

            function _dothing() {
                alert("_dothing");
            }

            function _doit() {
                _dothing();
                alert("_doit");
            }

            window.K = { doit : _doit };

        })();
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    // I DO CONTROL THIS CODE
    <script>

        function mydoit() {
            alert("mydoit");
            _dothing();         <-- THIS FAILS, IS THERE ANY WAY TO SUCCEED? :(
        }

        window.K.doit = mydoit;
        window.K.doit();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see it out of your scope. I would copy&paste, is that an option?

Comment: Unfortunately no: for other reasons I can't duplicate _dothing() (pretend it does something magical that's not reproducible), and I can't touch the top script body.

Comment: No. Closure scope comes from the location of the function *declaration*, which can't be changed.

Comment: Would it matter if the old (overwritten) `_doit` was called (alerting `"_doit"`)?

Comment: _doit() just calls _dothing() or it does something else that you don't want?

Comment: Pato: yeah, it something I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use jQuery to get the content of the script tag and after that you can use `eval` see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403108/calling-eval-in-particular-context).

Comment: Yes it exists outside your scope so I think the only way to get access to it is parse the script and use eval.

Answer (score 1):

When you put code inside this:

```
(function() {

})();
```

it's called a self invoking function, and creates a scope that you can't access (just like not being able to access a function's scope anywhere else...only inside of it) - it is run as soon as it is declared. The fact that you can call `window.K.doit` is because the code **extends** the **global** `window` object. Since you have access to `window` everywhere, it can be called, but only with `window.K.doit` or `K.doit`. This is how jQuery plugins are normally defined - they extend the global `jQuery` object without exposing any of their code directly. Sooooo no, you are not able to access it unless you do something like what the other answerer proposes - but be careful with using `eval`, as TECHNICALLY, any script could be inserted and you could "assume" it's right/trusted and eval it.

Comment: Doh. Unfortunately I don't think I can even do the eval trick. The first block of code (the one I don't control) actually is 'injected' into a UIWebView on iOS using stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString. So I don't even know where that context would be. I guess I'm hosed :(

Comment: But can't you wait until it's injected and read in the javascript? Or is it already evaluated when it's injected?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (I know this is very nasty, but, as others pointed out, it seems to be the only way):

```
function mydoit() {
    alert("mydoit");
    _dothing();
}

var f = new Function(document.scripts[0].text.replace(/(}\)\(\);\s*)$/, "window._dothing = _dothing;\n$1"));
f();
window.K.doit = mydoit;
window.K.doit();
```

Tested on Firefox, Chrome and IE8.

Beware: this is creating a hole new context, it's not the same as the already created.
It is calling just a copy of `_dothing`, not the original.

Comment: Massively hacky, and it just might work! Testing now with our (a bit more complicated) actual use case...

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a global variable from within the anonymous / self executing function: this tutorial will show you how: http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2012/07/29/Make-Your-JavaScript-Better-With-Self-Executing-Anonymous-Functions.aspx

Comment: The OP said they have no control over the code they are trying to reach.