# javascript eval in context without using this keyword

Tags: javascript, eval

I am trying to execute eval within a particular context. I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859853/1972493) useful. However I am getting the following behavior in Chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 m. Not tried other browsers. The code I am using is the following:

```
function evalInContext(js, context) {
    return function() { return eval(js); }.call(context);
}


console.log(evalInContext('x==3', { x : 3})) // Throws
console.log(evalInContext('this.x==3', { x : 3})) // OK
```

However I expected the first call to `evalInContext` not to throw. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Unfortunately the linked answer is wrong. No idea how it got 26 upvotes.

Comment: Because it works @Bergi see answer below... `this` !== "scope"

Comment: @Campbeln I never confused `this` with variable scope. The first snippet in your answer still doesn't produce the result that's shown in the comments. Logging `this` inside the `example` function is a different thing than using `this` right in the `eval`ed code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Scope and Context are not the same

The way variable `x` is resolved has nothing to do with context. It is resolved by scope rules: does any of the closures define that variable? If not, look in the global object. At no point the variable is resolved by looking in the context.

You could have a look at [this article](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/).

The behaviour is not particular to `eval`, it is the same with other functions:

```js
"use strict";

var obj = { x : 3};
var y = 4;

function test() {
  console.log(this.x); // 3
  console.log(typeof x); // undefined
}

test.call(obj);

function test2() {
  console.log(this.y); // 4
  console.log(typeof y); // number
}

test2.call(window);
```

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. Any ideas about how I would go about having the variable within the eval expression resolved by a field of an object literal?

Comment: I have posted a solution to my problem below. Any feedback welcome!

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 10):

whilst I recommend the answer provided by @trincot and in particular the great link. I am posting here my solution to the problem I faced

```
function evalInContext(scr, context)
{
    // execute script in private context
    return (new Function( "with(this) { return " + scr + "}")).call(context);
}
```

The `with(this)` expression allows the member variables of the `context` object to be present in the execution scope of the expression `scr`.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/543820/1972493) to a similar question

Answer (score 4):

This is an alternative method (written in ES6):

```
 (new Function(...Object.keys(context), codeYouWantToExecute))(...Object.values(context));
```

Credits to Jonas Wilms for the answer.

Here is my explanation, since I did not initially understand how it worked:

```
let example = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a+ b')
```

is the same as creating the function and assigning it to `example`:

```
function(a,b) {
    return a + b
}
```

After that, you can call `example` like this: `example(2,6)` which returns 8.

But let's say you don't want to assign the function created by `new Function` to a variable and you want to immediately call it instead.

Then you can just do this:

```
new Function('a', 'b', 'return a+ b')(2,6)
```

The code snippet at the top of this post is essentially doing the same thing. It uses the spread operator to pass in the keys of the `context`  object like this:
`new Function(key1, key2, key3... lastkey, codeYouWantToExecute)`. It then  calls the newly created function and passes the values that correspond to each key with the spread operator.

Lastly, here is the answer compiled to ES5:

```
(new (Function.bind.apply(Function, [void 0].concat(Object.keys(context), [codeYouWantToExecute])))()).apply(void 0, Object.values(context));
```

Answer (score 1):

This evaluates expressions in a given context without the need to prefix vars with 'this'.

Has caveats but works fine.

Can also incorporate custom functions in the expression.

Just call an 'evaluate' function, passing in your expression, context and an optional function.

The context must be a flat structure (no nested elements) and the function must be referred to as 'fn' inside the string expression. Answer prints 11 in this case:

```js
var expression = "fn((a+b)*c,2)";
var context = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var func = function(x,y){return x+y;};

function evaluate(ex, ctx, fn) {
return eval("var "+JSON.stringify(ctx).replace(/["{}]/gi, "").replace(/:/gi, "=")+", fn="+fn.toString()+";"+ex);
}

var answer = evaluate(expression, context, func);
console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

cannot comment so i post, Joe's answer is great but if the string holds multiple statements (like `x++; y++; x+y;`) the `y++` part would never be executed because it returns at first statement.

with this modification all statements will be executed and the last statement will be the return value.

> ```
> function evalInScopeAndContext(scr, scopeAndContext)
> {
>     // execute script in private context
>     return (new Function( "with(this) { return eval('" + scr + "'); }")).call(scopeAndContext);
> }
> ```

i also changed the parameter name because that parameter is used both as scope and context, and they are different things.

Warning 1:

When using this function `this.x` will equal to `x` and cannot be changed, because the `this` property of the scope will be shadowed if present.

if you execute `evalInScopeAndContext('this', {a:1, b:2, this:3})`
the answer will be `{a:1, b:2, this:3}` instead of `3`.

To access the property `this`, you have to write `this.this` instead, i don't think it can be fixed.

Warning 2:

Outer scope (From the caller of this function up to `window`) can be accessed and modified unless shadowed by the scope object.

So if you plan to execute something like `location = 'house';` but forget to insert the `location` key inside the scope object, you will execute `window.location = 'house'` and might cause damage.

Instead `this.location = 'house';` is always safe because `this` always exists and will just add the `location` key to the scope object provided, so you might want to always use `this.` as a prefix