# Javascript - eval in context/scope without using this keyword without with statement

Tags: javascript, scope, eval, with-statement

This post provides a solution for how to use eval within a particular context/scope without having to preface all variables/functions in the eval'd code with `this`. [javascript eval in context without using this keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107919/javascript-eval-in-context-without-using-this-keyword)

To clarify - let's say I have the following object as the context for an eval statement `{dog: "labrador"}`. I'd like `console.log(eval(dog))` to output "labrador" without having to type `eval(this.dog)`

However, the solution in the linked post:

```
function evalInContext(scr, context)
{
    // execute script in private context
    return (new Function( "with(this) { return " + scr + "}")).call(context);
}
```

uses the `with` statement. Considering usage of the `with` statement is discouraged, is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Why are you using this function at all? It looks like a long-winded, dangerous, and inefficient way to write: `context[scr]`

Comment: Apologies, that function was taken from the linked SO post as an example of how to refer to `dog` without doing `this.dog` when using eval in a particular context. I'm not using that function.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem you are trying to solve with eval

Comment: Please elaborate. `context[scr]` does respond to your "if I have an object... then I'd be able to ... without `this.dog`". So what is the problem?

Comment: Why not `with(context) { eval(src) }` ?

Comment: @JonasW. I don't want to use `with` due to it being disabled in strict mode.

Comment: @Quentin I updated the post with more details.

Comment: `Object.assign(window, context)` ?

Comment: @Roymunson - That doesn't really clarify things. Why are you evaling code in the first place? `eval` is even more discouraged that `with`.

Comment: @Quentin I need to run user code.

Comment: @roymunson on clientside: just set the variables in window maybe? on serverside: don't.

Comment: If you're sticking to `eval` (or `new Function()`), then sticking to `with` is not the issue.

Comment: The term "context" has a particular meaning in JS, and it is not what you are using it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there an alternative solution?

Sure but thats way worse than `with` :

```
 return new Function(...Object.keys(context), scr)(...Object.values(context));
```

Comment: Interesting, how does this work? I understand the `...` is spread notation - but I'm not sure how this expression  executes code  considering there is no call to `eval`. Also why would this be worse than `with`?

Comment: @roymunson it creates a function with a few parameters and then calls that function passing in the parameters. It is worse than eval as no one will understand it