# How can I use 'this' inside an eval statement?

Tags: javascript

```
function SomeFunc()
{
    this.var1 = 123;
    this.evalStr = "console.log('myvar:' + this.var1)";
}

var sf = new SomeFunc();

eval(sf.evalStr); // returns "myvar: undefined"
```

I'd like eval to take into account variables on my instantiated object, how can I do this?

**EDIT:** that question you marked as duplicate is way more complex than what I'm asking. I'm talking about evaling a string here.

**EDIT:** hey my question shouldn't get downvoted just because I dared to say "eval". sheesh. if you look down you'll see the answers are quite useful.

Comment: Do you **have** to use `eval`? Surely there's a better way

Comment: yes I have to use eval

Comment: `eval` executes code in the callee local context. In your case, `this` is global context, i.e. `window`.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403108/calling-eval-in-particular-context

Comment: If you really need to use `eval` so badly, please have the courtesy to tell us why. Right now, your question amounts to "I need to use `eval`, trust me. Now tell me how to do this awkward thing with it."

Comment: You probably don’t have to use `eval`.

Comment: I'm using a content editable div just for that function. So the user can edit that code using a web based ide and run it.

Comment: `this.evalFn = function() {console.log("myval:" + this.var1); };`. Then, do `sf.evalFn()`.

Comment: torazaburo, I want my eval func as a string

Comment: Why do you want the eval func as a string?

Comment: Sounds like `sf.editableFunction = new Function("console.log('myvar: ' + this.var1);"); sf.editableFunction();` is closer to what you need, then.

Comment: also, this code is not for end users. just for me so can be as hacky as heart's content.

Comment: @Ryan - Why the empty-string first argument?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Personal preference (I don’t like overloads that shift arguments left). Will take it out for here.

Comment: what do you mean by "new Function" isn't that a reserved word. also, if you can answer down there I can give you props

Comment: You’re getting downvoted because your question has an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), not because you mentioned `eval`. Having a lot of reputation doesn’t mean you automatically write good questions. But you can edit it to reflect the problem you’re actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `evalInContext` function in the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403108/calling-eval-in-particular-context) does exactly what you're asking for. Just call it with `sf.evalStr` and `sf`:

```js
function SomeFunc() {
  this.var1 = 123;
  this.evalStr = "console.log('myvar:' + this.var1)";
}

var sf = new SomeFunc();

function evalInContext(js, context) {
  return function() {
    return eval(js);
  }.call(context);
}
evalInContext(sf.evalStr, sf); // logs myvar:123
```

**However**, you'd be much better off using a constructed function. They're not quite as horrible as `eval()`:

```js
function SomeFunc() {
  this.var1 = 123;
  this.evalStr = "console.log('myvar:' + this.var1)";
}

var sf = new SomeFunc();

new Function(sf.evalStr).call(sf);  // logs myvar:123
```

Comment: hot damn this was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: fwiw, i think this answer's 2nd part is the way to go, i was just showing how to give the meaning to `this` you specifically asked for, but `Function` is leaner and meaner. it's actually a good question, even if you get drive-bys from evalphobes...

Comment: yeah I'm kind of digging this new Function() thing. never saw that until today. I did like your answer too though.

Comment: @foreyez The Run code snippet button creates an iframe that posts a request to http://stacksnippets.net/js, which returns an HTML page containing the JavaScript that was entered and that JavaScript executes. So no, it doesn't use `new Function()` or `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you need something like this:

```
function SomeFunc()
{
    this.var1 = 123;
    this.evalStr = "console.log('myvar:' + this.var1)";
    this.eval = function(){return eval(this.evalStr)};
}

var sf = new SomeFunc();

sf.eval(); // returns "myvar: 123"
```

that keeps the context inside the constructor, where `this` means what you think it means.

If you want to keep it external, you have to use `Function` to give `this` meaning in dynamic code. In older versions of firefox, a 2nd argument to `eval` would provide context, but that functionality was deprecated and removed, probably because `Function` can handle that use-case.